# How to create pod in Mesosphere with container type as Docker?

Tags: docker, mesos, mesosphere, dcos, kubernetes-mesos

I am trying to create a pod in Mesosphere but there is no option in configuration to define container type as Docker. Default container type getting launched is Mesos.

Answer (score 3):

Pods in Mesos only supports the Mesos Containerizer, which you can use to launch Docker containers or other containers. Building pods into Mesos meant changing the executor that the containerizer launches when it sees a pod definition. For more info see the Marathon [documentation](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/pods.html).